# Facebook Application that can import comma separated value (.csv) files

Tags: php, asp.net-mvc, facebook

I am very new to facebook application development.
In my facebook app I want to import CSV file and then i want to show the 
content on canvas.

can any of you please help me out by guiding few helpful points.
So that i can actually find out how to start this.

I can develop this app either in ASP.net or PHP . No issue in any of these.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you RTFM yet?  http://developers.facebook.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a good place to get started with the concepts behind [creating a facebook application](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas/). Depending on what else your app needs to do (select friends, send invites, ...) I'd probably go with an iframe app, here is a stack overflow answer on the [differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4727413/fbml-fbjs-xfbml) between an FBML FB app and an iframe FB app.

I'm a php guy, so I can't comment on ASP, but importing a csv file is super easy in PHP. You would use the function [fgetcsv](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) on the csv file uploaded by the user, or the function [str_getcsv](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) if the user is inputing the file contents into a dialog.

Comment: no problem, btw I'm EricsonW578 on the facebook developers forums.